# How to derive the new wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, wave-equation

I have a question that: Considering the 1D wave equation $u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0$ in the domain $0\leq x \leq s(t)$ where $s(t)$ be a given positive function. Changing the variable $y = \frac{x}{s(t)}$, and taking $w(y,t) = u(s(t)y,t) = u(x,t)$. What is the wave equation for $w(y,t)$ ? Anyone can help me to calculate ?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to solve the equation for $u(x,t)$ and then rewrite in terms of $w$? Anyway you can simply use the chain rule.

Comment: Same as [changing variable wave equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177787/changing-variable-wave-equation)

Comment: I do not know how to compute, can you help me ?